# Sending AT commands from Powershell script to Android phone via adb

Tags: android, powershell, command, adb, at-command

I have a little script that I run in adb shell of Android phone (/system/etc directory), which enables to communicate with the modem by sending/receiving a single AT command.
The script itself, if run in adb shell, works OK. That's what it looks like:

```
cat /dev/pts/7 &  
echo -e $1\\r > /dev/pts/7
```

Here's the output in adb shell:

```
# ./sendATCommand "at+cops?"
./sendATCommand "at+cops?"
#
+COPS: 0,0,"AT&T",6

OK
/dev/pts/7: invalid length
(need to press ENTER to return control to adb shell)

#
```

Now I want to invoke this script from a powershell script running on my PC, thus eventually controlling modem via AT commands, but nothing happens.
For example, the below powershell script will send the command at+cops? to check the operator to which mobile is registered to:

```
$adb = [IO.Path]::Combine([IO.Path]::Combine($Env:ANDROID, "platform-tools"), "adb.exe")  
& $adb remount  

$atCommand = "at+cops?"  
& $adb shell /system/etc/sendATCommand $atCommand
```

The output may looks sometimes like +ATCMD (any residual [proprietary]AT command sitting in device buffer after bootup), or at+cops?(echo), or nothing at all, but
never +COPS: 0,0,"AT&T",6 which I expect. Could you help me figure out what's going on and how to possibly fix it? Ideally
I want to be able to execute at command, return control to powershell, and have output available for further processing.
I am also open to other solutions to implement same thing.
Would greatly appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Does the same thing work from cmd.exe? Smells like an argument passing problem. Try quoting to pass quotes to adb.exe like this `& $adb shell /system/etc/sendATCommand """$atCommand"""`.

Comment: Thanks for the clue Andy, I did not get a chance to try it; will do it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to answer your question, my phone is not an Android, but when I connect it via buetooth or USB to my computer a COM port is created. So I build an assembly tool on the top of [.NET SerialPort class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) that allow, for example, to send SMS using the phone Modem.

I think it's usable in your case.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I already have it implemented this way (i.e. having modem communicate with PC via serial port), but I truly need ability to exercise AT communication between AP and modem from adb shell.